# Is there a way to increase the size of Mac OS X mouse "press and drag" behavior?

Tags: macos, mac, mouse

I use a tablet and a lot of buttons (such as Chrome's back button in the browser) have this weird behavior where if you press *and drag* a button by a pixel or two, you get a popup menu instead of the default mousedown behavior.

I hate that.

I want to at least increase the drag distance before that popup menu appears, to something like 5 times its default value.  Is there a way to do that?

[Note in Windows, you have to edit the registry to change this value](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/disable-drag-and-drop/), but I'm not sure what the equivalent change is in Mac OS X.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the usual click-and-hold behavior, and you're simply holding the button for too long?

Comment: It happens _both_ on click and _move_ or click and _hold_.  Because I'm using a tablet, even a fast tap can mean "click and move", if my hand moves but 2px.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't realized that happened in Chrome, but you're right, it does. I'm not sure if this is a system behavior or if it's coded into the app, though, so it could be hard to change. Good question though!

Comment: It happens in XCode too, for almost _all_ the menus.  If you're not using a tablet, it probably does not happen accidentally